# qt mysql query giving different result on different machine

Tags: sql, mysql, qt

Following code works on my pc but gives error on other pc's. how is it possible to run this successfully on all machines.

```
QSqlQuery query;
QString queryString = "SELECT * FROM " + parameter3->toAscii() + " WHERE " + parameter1->toAscii() + " = \"" + parameter2->toAscii() + "\"";
bool retX = query.exec(queryString);
```

What pre requisite should be fulfilled for this to run on any pc

Comment: SQL-injection attack waiting to happen.

Comment: Have you tried running the query apart from the application code? If so, what was returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In troubleshooting, if you isolate your query and it returns the result you anticipated ( such as you have done utilizing qt creator to verify the query returns a result of true), the next step would be to take a close look at your code and verify that you are passing the proper parameters into the query for execution.

I have a virgin machine I utilize for this purpose.  I am a software engineer by trade and I am fully aware that i have a ton of software installed on my PC which the common user may/will not have installed.  So the virgin allows me to test the code in stand-alone form.

I suggest implementing a message box prior to the execution of your query which shows the query to be executed.  This will verify the query is correct on the "other machines".

Comment: messagebox show correct names from table. the dll's used are qsqlmysql4.dll, qsqlmysqld4.dll, mingwm10.dll, QtCore4.dll, QtCored4.dll, QtGuid4.dll. Could that be the question area.

Comment: QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    // data necessary for the connection
    db.setHostName("xxx.xxx.xx.xx");
    db.setDatabaseName("xxxxxxxx");
    db.setUserName("xxxxx");
    db.setPassword("xxxx");
    db.open();

    QSqlQuery query;
    QString queryString = "SELECT * FROM " + parameter3->toAscii() + " WHERE " + parameter1->toAscii() + " = \"" + parameter2->toAscii() + "\"";
    bool retX = query.exec(queryString);
    QMessageBox::information(0,"",QString::number(retX));
    return retX;

Answer (score 0):

Certain dll's were needed. in my case qtguid4.dll, qtcored4.dll and qtsqld4.dll. There was a size difference. Once matched it worked on a pc. However, on other pc's i still get an error "The application failed to initialize 0xc000007b ....."

How is it possible to make an application run.

Brgds,

kNish